# Why can we eliminate the Doppler-broadened background by chopping the pump beam?

Tags: optics, laser, spectroscopy

In Wolfgang Demtröder (auth.) - Atoms, Molecules and Photons we have this laser spectroscopic setup.

[image]

Without any explanation he claims the chopper can fix the Doppler broadening background shown on this graph here:

[image]

(a) Doppler-broadened overlapping absorption proﬁles with small Lamb dips.

(b) Elimination of the Doppler-broadened background by chopping the pump beam.

I can't understand why it's possible. I would love your help.

Comment: The chopper is used to get the lock-in amplifier to work, extracting the part of the signal in phase with the chopped beam.